# How can I appeal a deletion for "promotion"?

Tags: support

I posted two answers on two similar questions [1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45114/do-other-search-engines-support-googles-hash-bang-syntax-for-crawling-ajax-ap/67532?noredirect=1#comment75528_67532), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55473/is-using-for-ajax-urls-the-standard-when-it-comes-to-seo/67533?noredirect=1#comment75527_67533).

Both were deleted with the same message:

> Promotion of specific websites like imelda immobilien is not permitted
>   here. –  Stephen Ostermiller♦

My answer was not promoting the web site, I was just using it as an example. My use of the site (with which I have no personal affiliation, I simply know the people behind it) proves a point. In my opinion my answer was valid, and added genuinely useful information to the question.

Is there any way to appeal the deletion? I spent time and effort writing the answer, I found the questions while trying to find a definitive answer to the questions. After I couldn't do so, I figured out the answer my self, and then wanted to help other folks save the hassle. It feels like a smack in the face for somebody to delete my answers because they contain a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meta question is the best way contacting the moderators here for an appeal in a situation like this.

As a moderator, one of my jobs is to deal with spam postings.  We typically get several a day and they are usually:

- From a new user
- Includes little more than a link

I am pretty quick to push the delete button on any post that meets those criteria.

Your answer seemed like it could be useful.  I looked at your other posts to see if you had a spammy posting history.   I saw that your only other post had the same link.  At that point, I deleted without further investigation.

On your word that you have no affiliation with the site, I am willing to un-delete the answers in question.

Comment: I had seen these deleted questions and wondered about this too given that they seemed to address the question in some detail, with a link unrelated to the typical webmaster products/services/blog, but didn't think it could be easily edited to replace the link with a generic one while maintaining the OP's point. Maybe we should ask them to disclose any affiliation to the site(s) first, and notate to review them again for a response in say 24-48 hours?

Comment: Given his reputation on other stackexchange sites, I'm willing to trust him in this case.

Comment: Right, that's something I look at too. I had meant that maybe when there's enough detail in an answer, we can ask them to disclose any affiliation _prior_ to deleting?

Comment: I'm pretty happy with the shoot first and ask questions later approach to spam fighting.  We do get a fair amount of inappropriate attempted self-promotion.  I'm happy to revisit any cases in which we make mistakes.

Comment: Most spam usually isn't that detailed in regards to answering the question. I think for answers like these, we probably should look at them in more depth (e.g., like what is the link to, does it pertain to the post or something obviously promotional, as well as their reputation on other sites...) and ask for their affiliation to links first when it's not clear. Of course there may be oversights when a flag is involved, like was the case here.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I can see that the posts might look spammy with no history. Appreciate the undelete. :-)